# How do I split arrays using a while loop?

Tags: ruby

I want to write a program that splits an array into two arrays, where any element in one array is smaller than any element in the other array.

The input that I have is:

```
a = [6, 45, 23, 65, 17, 48, 97, 32, 18, 9, 88]
```

And I'd like output like this:

```
[6, 23, 17, 18 , 9] < [45, 65, 48, 97, 32, 88]
```

I've tried:

```
i = 0
max = 0

while i < a.size
  if a[i] > max
    max = a[i]
  end
  i+=1
end

puts "this is the larger array: " + max.to_s
```

Which is completely off. As I am new to this, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the criteria of where the two arrays should split? Should they be of equal length or any other criteria?

Comment: thanks hirolau, i should have mentioned that. Yes around the same size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
small, large = a.sort!.shift(a.size/2) ,a

p small, large 
#=> [6, 9, 17, 18, 23]
#=> [32, 45, 48, 65, 88, 97]
```

Comment: Thanks hirolau, and is that ruby?

Comment: No Rails syntax here, there were some changes between 1.8 and 1.9 in how parallel assignment works, but I think it should work on 1.8+.

Comment: Thanks hirolau, that's perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
newarray = a.sort.each_slice((a.size/2.0).round).to_a
```

It will give you an array containing your split array:

```
newarray = [[6,9,17,18,23,32],[45,48,65,88,97]]
```

In this case, if you have an odd number of elements in your array, the first array returned will always have the extra element.  You can also save the arrays separately if you would like, but this way you can call each of the halves with newarray[0] and newarray[1].  If you want to split them simply add:

```
b = newarray[0]
c = newarray[1]
```

Comment: I don't know how I overlooked this, thanks sabrams this is awesome!

Comment: No need to round. Just divide by 2 instead of 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a while loop - sort the array and then split it in two

```
a.sort
a.in_groups_of( a.size/2)


a.sort.each_slice( a.size/2) probably does the trick without rails.
```

Comment: This works, but only if you're using rails, ruby does not have in_groups_of

Comment: Well I did say it shows *roughly* how :-P
There's an example below which does it using only Ruby...

Comment: Sorry should have specified I need strictly Ruby, but thanks vogomatix I will be sure to use your solution when I hop into rails.

Comment: Your rails solution will work only if the array is even, check my solution below to see how to manage odd instances.

Comment: It's really not very helpful to offer a guess of what might work in a language one does not know.

Comment: it is helpful to suggest that the original algorithm (using a while loop) was the wrong idea and that the problem should be approached differently

Comment: In a comment, perhaps.

Comment: The question was what is known as an XY question i.e. asking about X when the real solution is to do something entirely different (Y). I agree my answer had some rough edges, but it was the first answer and all the other answers followed on the same pattern. The minor errors in my original answer could equally have been solved through comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to preserve order, as in your example:

```
def split_it(a,n)
  f = a.select {|e| e <= n}
  [f, a-f]
end

a = [6, 45, 23, 65, 17, 48, 97, 32, 18, 9, 88]

f, l = split_it(a,23)
puts "#{f} < #{l}" # => [6, 23, 17, 18, 9] < [45, 65, 48, 97, 32, 88]
```

If you want to preserve order and have the first subarray contain `nbr` elements, add this:

```
def split_nbr(a, nbr)
  n = 1
  loop do
    return [] if n > a.max
    b = split_it(a,n)
    return b if b.first.size == nbr
    n += 1
  end   
end

f, l = split_nbr(a,3)
puts "#{f} < #{l}" # => [6, 17, 9] < [45, 23, 65, 48, 97, 32, 18, 88]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [6, 45, 23, 65, 17, 48, 97, 32, 18, 9, 88]
a = a.sort
print a.shift(a.count/2), " < " , a 
#=> [6, 9, 17, 18, 23] < [32, 45, 48, 65, 88, 97]
```

Another variation

```
a = [6, 45, 23, 65, 17, 48, 97, 32, 18, 9, 88]
a = a.sort
print a.values_at(0..a.count/2), " < ", a.values_at((a.count/2)+1 .. -1)
#=> [6, 9, 17, 18, 23] < [32, 45, 48, 65, 88, 97]
```